# powerMock does not throw exception, it actually goes into the method

Tags: mockito, cdi, private

This is my code snippet:

```
PowerMockito
            .doThrow(new Exception())
            .when((spy),
                    method(Mocked.class, "privateMethod", MyParameter.class))
            .withArguments(parameter);

actualObject.publicMethod();
```

Here, I have a public method which calls `privateMethod`. I have a Mocked class which I have declared as:

```
   @InjectMocks 
    Mocked mocked;
```

But by doing so, Mockito is not throwing any exception when it gets into the mocked class, and when private method is encountered it does not throw an exception.

In `when()`, should there always be a spy object, but the problem here is JUnit actually runs the private method, which I don't want. I need to simply throw an exception whenever this private method is called, so I can to cover all the catch blocks (which is not happening).

Comment: Did you try "@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)" annotation at the class-level of the test case.

Comment: yes I tried with this, but nothing works :-(

Comment: What type is "parameter"?

Comment: parameter is a class defined by me. for eg: DataHolder.class

Answer (score 0):

Add @PrepareForTest for the class.